# Connecting peak voltage, RMS, line-to-line and line-to-neutral

Tags: voltage, mains, three-phase, rms, single-phase

In EU the line-to-neutral voltage from a power outlet which is single phase (if I understand correctly) is 230V RMS and 50Hz. Then the line-to-line voltage (for the three-phase connection coming to the house) is: $$ 230 V_\text{RMS} \cdot \sqrt{3} = 398V_\text{RMS} $$
***As this is RMS, does it mean that the peak voltage between two lines is:***

$$ 398 V_\text{RMS} \cdot \sqrt{2} = 563V_ \text{peak}$$

?

Comment: *yes* ~ V_{L-N}*\$√3√2~~ [{rms}]=[V_{L-L}] _{pp}\$  next question?

Comment: The peak voltage can be higher during surges; maybe up to 1500 volts.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, wait it can't be peak-to-peak though, roght? Do you mean Vpeak?

Comment: Good Catch  563Vpeak  . ignore pp subscript   .. Do EU homes really have the option for 3 phase 230 V?  . NA only has 240 Split phase